# *ngSwitchCase with interpolation

Tags: angular, typescript

Seeking help and suggestion if this is possible to achieve. Here's the scenario i have this template that displays certain buttons with different functions and labels.

the current implementation is using *ngSwitchCase to determine which page the user isn navigation to and display specific button to that page.

My question here is, is it possible to interpolate inside the *ngSwitchCase?

```
*ngSwitchCase="'account/song'"
```

i want it to interpolate with a dynamic value coming from the url something like this

```
*ngSwitchCase="'account/song/{{ orderId }}'"
```

any suggestions and help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Does this work? `*ngSwitchCase="'account/song/' + orderId"`

Comment: Let's make a step back to look at the big picture here. Why not just use an ngIf in this case? A switch is to handle a know set of values individually. If you want something dynamic, why not just use an ngIf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular, you cannot directly interpolate variables or expressions inside `*ngSwitchCase`. However, you can achieve dynamic behavior by using `*ngIf` and binding the condition to a variable or expression that evaluates to true or false. Here's how you can achieve the desired functionality using `*ngIf`:

Assuming you have a component property `orderId` that holds the dynamic value from the URL, you can create a condition for each case in your template using `*ngIf` like this:

```html
<div [ngSwitch]="page">
  <button *ngIf="page === 'account/song'" (click)="doSomething()">Button for Account/Song</button>
  <button *ngIf="page === 'account/song/' + orderId" (click)="doSomethingElse()">Button for Account/Song with Order ID</button>
  <button *ngIf="page === 'other'" (click)="doOtherThing()">Button for Other Page</button>
</div>
```

In this example, `page` is assumed to hold the current page value. You can adjust the conditions and actions (e.g., `doSomething()`, `doSomethingElse()`, `doOtherThing()`) according to your specific requirements.

Remember to handle any changes to `orderId` and update the conditions accordingly in your component to reflect the dynamic behavior based on the URL.

Comment: thank you guys! i wasn't able to achieve it using the *ngSwitchCase instead i used the *ngIf which works perfectly fine